# Rows with dates between multiple conditions (excel only)

Tags: excel, date, conditional-statements

I have `Column A`:

```
str 11/9/2007
end 10/10/2008
str 11/14/2008
end 5/29/2009
str 11/27/2009
end 2/5/2010
str 10/8/2010
end 4/8/2011
str 4/29/2011
end 5/20/2011
str 7/8/2011
end 10/21/2011
```

and `Column B`:

```
9/6/2007
9/7/2007
9/10/2007
9/11/2007
9/12/2007
9/13/2007
9/14/2007
9/17/2007
9/18/2007
9/19/2007
9/20/2007
9/21/2007
9/24/2007
9/25/2007
9/26/2007
9/27/2007
9/28/2007
10/1/2007
10/2/2007
10/3/2007
10/4/2007
10/5/2007
10/8/2007
10/9/2007
10/10/2007
10/11/2007
10/12/2007
10/15/2007
10/16/2007
```

I'd like to insert `1` in the column next to `Column B` if `Column B` date is in any of the `start` and `end` range in `Column A`. So the expected output is something like:

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Any tips, please?

Comment: As of now I can't think of anything except for multiple `IFs`. This wont work as I have 100s of `start` and `end` dates ...

Comment: How would I refer to these two columns afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let s(i) and e(i) denote your start and end dates (i=1,2,3,...,N) and t a target date.

You need to find if there exists a value of i such that s(i)<=t<=e(i).

You can use the `MATCH` function to do this.

The s(i) and e(i) (i=1,2,3,...,N) should each be arranged (as suggested by commenter @pnuts) in a column in ascending order. Let `Start` and `End` respectively denote the ranges containing these columns of start and end dates. Let `Target` denote a target date, t.

`=MATCH(Target,Start,1)` returns the index of the date within `Start` which is the latest date which is on or before the target date. So it returns a candidate value for the index, i such that s(i)<=t. All that remains is to test whether e(i)>=t for this candidate value, ie

`=INDEX(End,MATCH(Target,Start,1))>=Target`

Generally, this will deliver `TRUE` if there exists a value of i such that s(i)<=t<=e(i) and `FALSE` otherwise. The exception to this occurs when the target date t occurs before the first start date s(1). In this case the error value `#N/A` is delivered. You can trap this with the `IFERROR` function to deliver `FALSE` instead and you can convert the booleans `TRUE` and `FALSE` to the 0 and 1 result you are looking for using the usual `--` (double negation) operation.

It is important that the start and end dates are arranged in ascending (earliest first) order. If not this solution will not work.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works well. Is it possible to change the output from this though? I mean sometimes on `start` dates items are being `bought` and some other cases on `start` dates items are being `sold`. If items are `bought` I want to have `1`, if `sold` then `-1`. Obviously, if the `target` date is not in the range then `0` printed out.

Comment: Created a new topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428780/index-and-match-with-an-additional-condition-excel-only

Comment: I have added an answer to your new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CheckingDates()
Dim Value1 As Date, Value2 As Date, Value3 As Date

For j = 1 To 12 Step 2
    For i = 1 To 29
        Value1 = Right(Range("A" & j), Len(Range("A" & j)) - 4)
        Value2 = Right(Range("A" & j + 1), Len(Range("A" & j + 1)) - 4)
        Value3 = Range("B" & i).Value
            If Value3 > Value1 And Value3 < Value2 Then
                Range("C" & i).Value = "1"
            End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but I cannot use VBA for this task :( +1 anyway.