# Index and match with an additional condition (excel only)

Tags: excel, date, conditional-statements

Continuing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416661/rows-with-dates-between-multiple-conditions-excel-only) topic, I would like to add one more condition. I have the following `start`, `end`, and `action` columns:

```
11/9/2007   10/10/2008  SELL
11/14/2008  5/29/2009   BUY
11/27/2009  2/5/2010    SELL
10/8/2010   4/8/2011    SELL
```

I also have `target` days (ex-weekends) starting from April 1, 2007 to today. I would like to do the following:

- If the `target` day is in the range of `start` and `end` dates
  **AND** `action` is `SELL`, then print out `-1`;
- If the `target` day is in the range of `start` and `end` dates
  **AND** `action` is `BUY`, then print out `1`;
- If the `target` day is not in the range of `start` and `end` dates, then print out `0`;

Any guidance/tips appreciated as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code will help you problem

```
Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date
Dim dDate As Date
Dim iCol As Integer

iCol = 2

Do While Cells(iCol, 2).Value <> ""
    dStart = Format(Cells(iCol, 2).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    dEnd = Format(Cells(iCol, 3).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    if dDate > dStart and dDate < dEnd then
        if Cell(iCol,4).Value = "SELL" then
            printout -1
        else
            printout 1
        end if
    else
        printout 0
    end if
    iCol = iCol + 1
Loop
```

If you just only need excel function

```
=IF(AND(J3 >= F3,J3 <= G3, H3="SELL"),-1,IF(AND(J3 >= F3,J3 <= G3, H3="BUY"),1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing in the style of my answer to the earlier question you cited...

Add an `index` column to your input table containing the values 1, 2, 3,... The expression
`=SUMPRODUCT((target>=start)*(target<=end)*index)` will indicate which row of your input table (if any) that `target` falls within. If the expression returns a value of 0 then the `target` does not fall within any of the date ranges. The expression relies on the date ranges not overlapping (so that a `target` can fall within at most 1 date range). If the date ranges can overlap then if a `target` falls within 2 or more date ranges the expression will return the sum of the indices of the ranges it falls in. This will be a problem since, for example, you won't be able to tell if a result of 3 means the `target` falls in the third date range or both of the first two.

Use the result from this expression as the second argument of an `INDEX()` function where the first argument is the `action` range. This will then deliver BUY, SELL or #N/A according to whether the `target` date falls within a  buy range, a sell range or not in any range. Convert these results to your desired +1, -1 and 0 using whatever method you want.